# Kitty can’t fix it — Old questions inaccessible for logged-in users, giving “unexpected error”

Tags: bug, status-completed, specific-question, 500-server-error

For the past few days, any attempt to access the question [Collecting proofs that finite multiplicative subgroups of fields are cyclic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic) results in an **internal server error**:

[image: screenshot: Oops! Something Bad Happened!]

It seems the poor kitten needs help from a human.

The front page indicates some activity on this question meanwhile, hence it cannot be broken for everyone. Moreover, I checked that I can access the question when I log out, but after I log back in, it’s broken again. This happens consistently across multiple devices (albeit on the same network).

The associated [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/54735/timeline) and [revisions](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/54735/revisions) pages work fine.

The same problem affects many more questions. As observed by [Sam Hopkins](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5584/kitty-can-t-fix-it-old-questions-inaccessible-for-logged-in-users-giving-une#comment28325_5584), they all seem to be $\ge10$ years old. [Martin Sleziak](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5584/kitty-can-t-fix-it-old-questions-inaccessible-for-logged-in-users-giving-une#comment28363_5584) found out an important distinguishing feature that all affected question have some deleted answers. Moreover, evidence suggests that the bug only happens for users with $\ge10$k reputation (possibly because they can see deleted answers).

It appears from [quick sampling](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5584/kitty-can-t-fix-it-old-questions-inaccessible-for-logged-in-users-giving-une#comment28368_5584) that about 2/3 of all old questions with deleted answers are affected by this bug, which means it’s likely **several thousands** of questions.

As for the cut-off date, the last question affected by the bug that I found is [Computing Ext in Exterior algebra (related to Koszul duality)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134595/computing-ext-in-exterior-algebra-related-to-koszul-duality) from June 24, 2013, which is the day before the integration of MathOverflow into the Stack Exchange network. Thus, it seems likely that the bug only affects questions from before the migration.

Based on further experiments, it appears a more precise criterion is that the bug affects questions that have a deleted answer that was deleted by June 24, 2013, except when the answer was deleted in a special way (e.g., [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132473/n-balls-covering-n-balls) the answer was converted to a comment; [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49303/mazurs-unpublished-manuscript-on-primes-and-knots) it was deleted by spam flags).

A small sample of questions exhibiting the problem as reported in the comments:

- [If you break a stick at two points chosen uniformly, the probability the three resulting sticks form a triangle is 1/4. Is there a nice proof of this?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/2014/if-you-break-a-stick-at-two-points-chosen-uniformly-the-probability-the-three-r),
- [Do sets with positive Lebesgue measure have same cardinality as R?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8972/do-sets-with-positive-lebesgue-measure-have-same-cardinality-as-r),
- [Chain homotopy: Why du+ud and not du+vd?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8974/chain-homotopy-why-duud-and-not-duvd),
- [Ordinals that are not sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8976/ordinals-that-are-not-sets),
- [Important results that use infinite-dimensional manifolds?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10200/important-results-that-use-infinite-dimensional-manifolds),
- [Why is addition of observables in quantum mechanics commutative?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14376/why-is-addition-of-observables-in-quantum-mechanics-commutative),
- [Is it possible to dissect a disk into congruent pieces, so that a neighborhood of the origin is contained within a single piece?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17313/is-it-possible-to-dissect-a-disk-into-congruent-pieces-so-that-a-neighborhood-o),
- [Is there an introduction to probability theory from a structuralist/categorical perspective?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical),
- [Polynomial bijection from $\mathbb Q\times\mathbb Q$ to $\mathbb Q$?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q),
- [Fermat numbers and the infinitude of primes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/22316/fermat-numbers-and-the-infinitude-of-primes),
- [Representations of Pin vs. Representations of Clifford](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24181/representations-of-pin-vs-representations-of-clifford),
- [Convergence of $\sum(n^3\sin^2n)^{-1}$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24579/convergence-of-sumn3-sin2n-1),
- [Is Thompson's Group F amenable?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26821/is-thompsons-group-f-amenable),
- [Is the Riemann Hypothesis equivalent to a $\Pi_1$ sentence?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence),
- [Fast matrix multiplication](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34173/fast-matrix-multiplication),
- [Is all ordinary mathematics contained in high school mathematics?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36580/is-all-ordinary-mathematics-contained-in-high-school-mathematics),
- [How to find the number of $k$-permutations of $n$ objects with $x$ types, and $r_1, r_2, r_3, \cdots , r_x$ = the number of each type of object?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37211/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r),
- [Demonstrating that rigour is important](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37610/demonstrating-that-rigour-is-important?page=2) (Note: only page 2 is problematic),
- [Awfully sophisticated proof for simple facts](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42512/awfully-sophisticated-proof-for-simple-facts),
- [Examples of ZFC theorems proved via forcing](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/42569/examples-of-zfc-theorems-proved-via-forcing) ,
- [Arguments against large cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44095/arguments-against-large-cardinals),
- [Proofs of the uncountability of the reals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46970/proofs-of-the-uncountability-of-the-reals),
- [Does "antichain" mean something different in set-forcing than in lattice theory?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47057/does-antichain-mean-something-different-in-set-forcing-than-in-lattice-theory),
- [Cantor's argument revisited](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47458/cantors-argument-revisited),
- [Nonessential use of large cardinals](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/48851/nonessential-use-of-large-cardinals),
- [Behaviour of power series on their circle of convergence](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49395/behaviour-of-power-series-on-their-circle-of-convergence),
- [Axiom of Symmetry, aka Freiling's argument against CH](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/49721/axiom-of-symmetry-aka-freilings-argument-against-ch),
- [Splitting infinite sets](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51171/splitting-infinite-sets),
- [Inconsistent theory with long contradiction](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/52070/inconsistent-theory-with-long-contradiction),
- [Collecting proofs that finite multiplicative subgroups of fields are cyclic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54735/collecting-proofs-that-finite-multiplicative-subgroups-of-fields-are-cyclic),
- [Slaman and Woodin on Mathematical logic](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/57094/slaman-and-woodin-on-mathematical-logic),
- [The disjunction property in Peano Arithmetic?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/63160/the-disjunction-property-in-peano-arithmetic),
- [Algebraic axiomatization for AB+BA^T operation on matrices](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71144/algebraic-axiomatization-for-abbat-operation-on-matrices),
- [Exact consistency-strength of "all projective sets are Ramsey"](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/76280/exact-consistency-strength-of-all-projective-sets-are-ramsey),
- [Fifth powers modulo a prime](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/78270/fifth-powers-modulo-a-prime),
- [Does $2^X=2^Y\Rightarrow |X|=|Y|$ imply the axiom of choice?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x-2y-rightarrow-x-y-imply-the-axiom-of-choice),
- [Intersection of an uncountable number of sets.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/96222/intersection-of-an-uncountable-number-of-sets),
- [Solovay's paper from AD+ that all sets are Ramsey](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106640/solovays-paper-from-ad-that-all-sets-are-ramsey),
- [If d/dx is an operator, on what does it operate?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115416/if-d-dx-is-an-operator-on-what-does-it-operate),
- [How are infinite-dimensional manifolds most commonly treated?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121306/how-are-infinite-dimensional-manifolds-most-commonly-treated),
- [Consistency strength of projective determinacy (PD)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/134321/consistency-strength-of-projective-determinacy-pd).

Comment: I'm getting the same error (with chrome on mac)

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/17313/is-it-possible-to-dissect-a-disk-into-congruent-pieces-so-that-a-neighborhood-o has been giving me Kitty for some time now.

Comment: Both are broken for me (Firefox, Android)

Comment: Another example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26821/is-thompsons-group-f-amenable

Comment: Another one : https://mathoverflow.net/questions/81204/does-2x-2y-rightarrow-x-y-imply-the-axiom-of-choice

Comment: And another: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/14376/why-is-addition-of-observables-in-quantum-mechanics-commutative

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/37211/how-to-find-the-number-of-k-permutations-of-n-objects-with-x-types-and-r

Comment: Two more: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/121306/, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10200

Comment: An obvious pattern: it looks like the problem appears only on old (10+ year old) questions, though certainly not *every* old question has this problem. For example https://mathoverflow.net/questions/21003/polynomial-bijection-from-mathbb-q-times-mathbb-q-to-mathbb-q is broken but https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free is ok.

Comment: Another one: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36580/is-all-ordinary-mathematics-contained-in-high-school-mathematics

Comment: Question 14376, reported here yesterday by @Jeremy, was bumped to the front page five hours ago by an answer posted by another user, https://mathoverflow.net/users/17261/jjcale?tab=activity – but I'm still getting Kitty. What is going on here?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, the question in my original report was also bumped to the front page while it was already broken for me, as I mentioned, so the bug only affects some users.

Comment: Added a few more examples.

Comment: yeah, saw these too. :-( time to relocate to a better platform?

Comment: logging out + clearing cookies  + logging back does not help

Comment: @TimCampion Could you or another moderator add a status-review tag so that the problem is actually noticed by staff?

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for the nudge. Added now.

Comment: @TimCampion Thank you.

Comment: I am not sure if https://mathoverflow.net/questions/20740/is-there-an-introduction-to-probability-theory-from-a-structuralist-categorical has already been mentioned

Comment: Not yet, adding it now. The list of questions is kept updated with all that have been identified; it’s sorted according to the post ID so that it is easy to check whether a given question has already been listed.

Comment: There are many, many more instances. If you go to one of the questions already in the list and look for questions with nearby post IDs then you will probably find several. For example, the first question currently in the list is number 8972, and 8974 and 8976 are also examples (8973 and 8975 are not questions). However, it doesn't seem to be a contiguous block of IDs that are affected: 8983 seems fine. Probably we're getting to the point where adding newly found instances to the list is not going to help much.

Comment: P.S. I’ve checked OEIS so that you don’t need to.

Comment: It's happening here, on Chrome from a Windows box:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/115416/if-d-dx-is-an-operator-on-what-does-it-operate .   Same page gives same problem on Firefox from the same Windows box and on Chrome from my Android phone.

Comment: I have been noticing the same, with a number of questions, e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/71144/algebraic-axiomatization-for-abbat-operation-on-matrices

Comment: I cannot test this myself - for some reason, the linked question work fine for me. Still I was curious whether people who get the error have access to pages such as [timeline](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/2014/timeline) or [revision history](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/2014/revisions), or whether they'll get the same error there.

Comment: @MartinSleziak Both of these work fine for me, on two affected questions that I tried.

Comment: I wonder whether the problem is tied to reputation, as all users so far who confirmed that they are affected by the bug have over 10K.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Since you've mentioned 10k+ users, I will add that all questions mentioned in the post have at least one deleted answer. (This is something which is different for users below and above 10k, and for users who are not logged in.) I have split this into two queries - [the first one](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1714897?list=2014,8972,8974,8976,10200,14376,17313,20740,21003,22316,24181,24579,26821,31846,34173,36580,37211,37610,42512,42569,44095,46970,47057,47458,48851,49395,49721) ...

Comment: ... and [the second one](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1714897?list=51171,52070,54735,57094,63160,71144,76280,78270,81204,96222,106640,115416,115416,121306). (Since the list is getting quite long.)

Comment: To elaborate, there are at least 3 confirmed users below 10k not affected by the bug (at least at some point): https://mathoverflow.net/users/8250/martin-sleziak (per https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5584/kitty-can-t-fix-it-old-questions-inaccessible-for-logged-in-users-giving-une#comment28360_5584), https://mathoverflow.net/users/17261/jjcale (per https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5584/kitty-can-t-fix-it-old-questions-inaccessible-for-logged-in-users-giving-une#comment28331_5584), and https://mathoverflow.net/users/471160/xyc (per https://mathoverflow.net/posts/54735/timeline).

Comment: @MartinSleziak You are onto something there. I just checked an old post that I remembered to have a deleted answer by myself, and sure enough, it's broken: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/67015/elementary-luroth-theorem-proof

Comment: If somebody wants to test this more thoroughly, one could use queries showing [questions with deleted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1714905/questions-with-deleted-answers?Date1=2011-01-01&Date2=2012-01-01) and [all questions with counts of deleted answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1714907/number-of-deleted-answers?Date1=2011-01-01&Date2=2012-01-01) within a given period. (To check whether other questions that have a deleted answer cause the same problem and whether questions with no deleted answers work fine.)

Comment: Thanks for creating the queries. Out of the first 20 questions on the first list, 14 give me kitty, 6 don’t (50872, 50912, 50915, 50966, 51056, 51068). Of the second list, all questions without deleted answers that I tried work fine.

Comment: Hey all, I spoke with the dev looking into this and she gave me a status update - we’ve identified the problem and are looking into how to fix it. We'll have more info soon. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: @Catija Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thank you all for reporting and excellent documentation of this issue! We have applied a fix and all the affected pages should now load as expected for logged in users as well as anonymous users.

As you all observed, the issue was indeed linked to older pre-migration post history deletion data which was formatted differently than it is today. Some code was released recently which did not handle the old history format, resulting in the error. This impacted both questions and answers but only in some conditions as you identified, i.e. the page would load if the post was flagged as spam/offensive.

The fix that was applied reformatted the old data so that we no longer need to be concerned with special handling, hopefully preventing headaches like this in the future.

Comment: Many thanks for this!

Comment: Thank you for fixing it!

Comment: Thank you for this! Who would have thought the migration would still make itself felt this much later?!

Answer (score 9):

This is not a resolution of the bug, but at least I have found a way around it: If I log out of my account the affected pages all become accessible. If I then log back in I get the "kitty" error, but logging out makes the page accessible again.

Comment: Yes, this is noted in the question.

Comment: ah, apologies, I had not read carefully, this answer then does not add anything, I will delete it.

Comment: Note: Instead of logging out, you can open an incognito tab on whatever browsers support this.

Comment: This is an okay temporary fix, but I really hope someone (at StackExchange support, I guess?) is aware of the bug and working on a real solution, because this is a big loss in functionality and has been going on a while now.